# Is it possible to invert a named scope in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

In my Rails3 model I have these two named scopes:

```
scope :within_limit,     where("wait_days_preliminary <= ? ", ::WAIT_TIME_LIMIT.to_i )
scope :above_limit,      where("wait_days_preliminary > ? ",  ::WAIT_TIME_LIMIT.to_i )
```

Based on their similarity, it would be natural for me to define the second by inverting the first.

How can i do that in Rails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arel has a `not` method you could use:

```
condition = arel_table[:wait_days_preliminary].lteq(::WAIT_TIME_LIMIT.to_i)
scope :within_limit, where(condition)     # => "wait_days_preliminary <= x"
scope :above_limit,  where(condition.not) # => "NOT(wait_days_preliminary <= x)"
```

Comment: Clever! Although your answer suggests i cannot define the first and then just "not" the first scope like so: `scope :above_limit, within_limit.not`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could work

```
scope :with_limit, lambda{ |sign| where("wait_days_preliminary #{sign} ? ", ::WAIT_TIME_LIMIT.to_i ) }

MyModel.with_limit(">")
MyModel.with_limit("<")
MyModel.with_limit(">=")
MyModel.with_limit("<=")
```