# How do I create a rails scope with an or or a not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a two scopes in my user model:

```
scope :hard_deactivated, where(:hard_deactivated => true)
scope :soft_deactivated, where(:soft_deactivated => true)
```

So far so good

### OR

I want to create a scope :deactivated, which will include all users where hard_deactivated is true OR soft deactivated is true. Obviously I could just do this:

```
scope :deactivated, where("hard_deactivated = ? or soft_deactivated = ?", true, true)
```

but this does not feel very dry.

### NOT

Also I would like to create an inverse scope :not_hard_deactivated. I could do this:

```
scope :not_hard_deactivated, where(:hard_deactivated => false)
```

but again, this feels bad, especially if my scope becomes more complex. There should be some way or warpping the SQL generated by the previous scope in a not clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an arel table:

```
hard_deactivated_true = arel_table[:hard_deactivated].eq(true)
soft_deactivated_true = arel_table[:soft_deactivated].eq(true)

scope :deactivated, where(hard_deactivated_true.and(soft_deactivated_true))
scope :not_hard_deactivated, where(hard_deactivated_true.not)
```

See: [Is it possible to invert a named scope in Rails3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574959/is-it-possible-to-invert-a-named-scope-in-rails3)

Answer (score 1):

For the "NOT" part, you can do something like this:

```
extend ScopeUtils

positive_and_negative_scopes :deactivated do |value|
  where(:hard_deactivated => value)
end
```

And implement this method in a separate module:

```
module ScopeUtils
  def positive_and_negative_scopes(name)
    [true, false].each do |filter_value|
      prefix = ("not_" if filter_value == false)
      scope :"#{prefix}#{name}", yield(filter_value)
    end
  end
end
```

Regarding the "OR" case, you might be something similar, depending on what your recurring pattern is. In the simple example above it's not worth it, as doesn't help readability.

```
scopes_with_adjectives_and_negatives :deactivated, [:soft, :hard]

module ScopeUtils
  def scopes_with_adjectives_and_negatives(name, kinds)
    kinds.each do |kind|
      positive_and_negative_scopes name do |filter_value|
        where("#{kind}_#{name}" => filter_value)
      end
    end
    scope :"#{name}", where(kinds.map{|kind| "#{kind}_#{name} = ?"}.join(" OR "), true, true)
    scope :"not_#{name}", where(kinds.map{|kind| "#{kind}_#{name} = ?"}.join(" AND "), false, false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use sql snippet in `where` method (like in your second example), or more 'sugar' gems like [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)